# lightweight charts import error in python

Tags: python-3.x, lightweight-charts

I have installed successfully lwc

`pip install lightweight_charts`

I get this error below at this line, please advise:

`from lightweight_charts import Chart`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\naveen\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\strat-0.29.py", line 14, in <module>
    from lightweight_charts import Chart
  File "C:\Users\naveen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\lightweight_charts\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .chart import Chart
  File "C:\Users\naveen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\lightweight_charts\chart.py", line 
8, in <module>
    from lightweight_charts.pywebview import _loop
  File "C:\Users\naveen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\lightweight_charts\pywebview.py", line 6, in <module>
    from lightweight_charts.js import LWC
  File "C:\Users\naveen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\lightweight_charts\js.py", line 47, in <module>
    class LWC:
  File "C:\Users\naveen\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\lightweight_charts\js.py", line 528, in LWC
    width: float = 0.5, height: float = 0.5, sync: bool | UUID = False):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'type'
```

Comment: was your question answered successfully?

Answer (score 2):

Try to upgrade python to v 3.10

Comment: yes ,this may be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to upgrade your python.

It works well for `python 3.10`.

Official git page says `3.9+`: [image]

---

Related link to error: https://github.com/tiangolo/typer/issues/371

Link to git: https://github.com/louisnw01/lightweight-charts-python